# Properly set up require.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

Here is where my files are

```
├── public
│   ├── require.js // downloaded from site
│   ├── config.js // generated from grunt-bower-requirejs
│   ├── app
│   ├── css
│   ├── vendor
│   │   ├── angular
│   │   ├── angular-bootstrap
│   │   ├── angular-ui-router
│   │   ├── bootstrap
│   │   ├── jquery
│   │   └── ngstorage
│   └── views
```

Here is my config.js

```
require.config({
  shim: {

  },
  paths: {
    angular: "vendor/angular/angular",
    "angular-bootstrap": "vendor/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls",
    "angular-ui-router": "vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router",
    bootstrap: "vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap",
    ngstorage: "vendor/ngstorage/ngStorage",
    require: "vendor/require/build/require.min"
  },
  packages: [

  ]
});
```

The code I have in my index.html is:

```
<script data-main="config" src="require.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script> // for angular
```

But the scripts don't seem to load as expected. I get an error that "angular" is not found on line 1 of app.js.

Comment: I'd suggest you shimmed the `angular-*` packages to require `angular` for a start. Then you may need to provide more details.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Sorry, what do you mean shimmed?

Comment: [Shim reference](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

Answer (score 0):

`paths: {
            angular: "vendor/angular/angular",
            "angular-bootstrap": "vendor/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls",
            "angular-ui-router": "vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router",
            bootstrap: "vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap",
            ngstorage: "vendor/ngstorage/ngStorage",
            require: "vendor/require/build/require.min"
    },
    shim: {
        "angular' : {"exports" : "angular"},
        "angular-bootstrap':["angular"],
        "angular-ui-router':["angular"]
    }
}`

Details about shim is referred to [requireJS API](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).You may need to check if your rest libs are follow [AMD specification](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD).

e.g   you have included ngStorage, look in to it, At the top of vendor/ngstorage/ngStorage.js, you can see some lines like this:

`if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define('ngStorage', ['angular'], function(angular) {`

in this piece,  " define('ngStorage', ['angular'] "  tell requireJS the model name is ngStorage and has one dependency : angular.

If a lib include in "paths" section has similar line, requireJS  will load it as dependency follow AMD, otherwise you need to write shim to make your lib support AMD specification.

Notice,  you may need to include jQuery as well as before look bootstrap.
in paths you should have
`'jquery': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min'`

and in shim you need:   "bootstrap": ["jquery"],